# Question about weak convergence to a constant

Tags: probability, convergence

Quick quesiton. I am aware that if you have an random variable st $X_n \rightarrow^{\mathrm{d}} X$, and $X$ is a constant, then $X_n \rightarrow^{\mathrm{p}} X$.

But does this mean that if $X_n \rightarrow^{\mathrm{d}} X$, then $X_n - X \rightarrow^{\mathrm{d}} 0$, and thus $X_n - X \rightarrow^{\mathrm{p}} 0$?

Comment: By "$c$" might you mean "$X$"?

Comment: Yes. Look at Slutsky's Lemma for a general result of this.

Comment: Ok. But why do i know that $X_n - X \rightarrow^d 0 $? from $X_n \rightarrow^d X$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $X_n$ converges in distribution to a non-constant $X$, it need not follow that the difference converges in distribution to zero. For one thing, the $X_n$ need not be defined on the same probability space as $X$, so subtraction makes no sense.

If everything is defined on the same probability space, here is a counterexample: On $\Omega=[0,1]$ define $X(\omega)=\omega$ and set $X_n := 1 - X$ for every $n$. Clearly everybody has uniform distribution over $[0,1]$ so that $X_n\to X$ in distribution, but $X_n-X=1-2X$ has uniform distribution over $[-1,1]$ and does not converge in distribution to zero. (For a discrete example let $X$ take values $0,1$ with equal probability and define $X_n=1-X$ as before.)

OTOH if you already know that $X_n\stackrel P\to X$ (whether or not the limit $X$ is constant), then automatically $X_n-X\stackrel P\to0$ by the definition of convergence in probability.